# Prove that if $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $k^4+2k^3+k^2$ is divisble by $4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I am trying to solve by induction and have established the base case (that the statement holds for $k=1$).

For the inductive step, I tried showing that the statement holds for $k+1$ by expanding $(k+1)^4+2\cdot(k+1)^3+(k+1)^2$, but this equals $16k^4+34k^3+3k^2+16k+4$, and $4$ cannot be factored out.

Comment: Are you required to use induction?

Comment: Why do you have $(2k+1)^4$ and not $(k+1)^4$?

Comment: You can use $k^4+2k^3+k^2=(k(k+1))^2$ instead of induction ($k,k+1$ are two consecutive integers and so $2$ divides $k(k+1)$ and so $4$ divides $(k(k+1))^2$).

Comment: I am not required to use induction, but that is the method I use for most of these types of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\underline{\text{Proof by induction:}}$

**First, show that this is true for $k=1$:**

$1^4+2\cdot1^3+1^2=4$

**Second, assume that this is true for $k$:**

$k^4+2k^3+k^2=4n$

**Third, prove that this is true for $k+1$:**

$(k+1)^4+2(k+1)^3+(k+1)^2=$

$4(k+1)^3+\color{red}{k^4+2k^3+k^2}=$

$4(k+1)^3+\color{red}{4n}=$

$4[(k+1)^3+n]$

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

---

$\underline{\text{Proof by modular-arithmetic:}}$

**Consider the following cases:**

- $k\equiv0\pmod4 \implies k^4+2k^3+k^2\equiv0+0+0\equiv0\pmod4$
- $k\equiv1\pmod4 \implies k^4+2k^3+k^2\equiv1+2+1\equiv4\equiv0\pmod4$
- $k\equiv2\pmod4 \implies k^4+2k^3+k^2\equiv16+16+4\equiv36\equiv0\pmod4$
- $k\equiv3\pmod4 \implies k^4+2k^3+k^2\equiv81+54+9\equiv144\equiv0\pmod4$

Please note that this method is handy only when dealing with a relatively small divisor.

Comment: Thank you, your solution made the most sense to me and fits in my inductive step.

Comment: @user3699546: You're welcome... Feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it if you think it is the most accurate one :)

Comment: WOW. And so the addiction just increases...hahaha

Comment: I have to wait 3 minutes.

Comment: What do you mean by addiction?

Comment: @MagicMan: Damn you've got it me again, crash! I was relying on you not being around at the exact point in time I was. But I swear it's my first (and hopefully last) answer for today...

Comment: @barakmanos Hahaha. I nearly lost it when I saw your answer lol. I was like no way! We can't stop!!! Induction problems really are tempting though...like a tasty morning snack. Almost better than milk and cookies. Almost.

Comment: @user3699546 By "addiction" we simply mean that barak manos and I have sort of formed a ... bond? ... by answering the same questions simultaneously it seems *and also* claiming that we are trying to be less active on MSE. But that is proving to be a futile task.

Comment: @MagicMan: hahaha... man this is getting pathetic, we both need some serious help here!

Comment: Haha, at least its just not math and meth.

Comment: @user3699546: I just might get tempted and switch if it carries on like this...

Comment: @barakmanos I do agree! You know what would be fun? Putting our templates up for comparison by the populace. Yours is nice with the colors, something I usually refrain from. Advantages and disadvantages of both. I swear my greatest disadvantage is how **long** it takes me to write it all up. I try to make it as clear as possible, but seeing answers plopping in is like brrr. haha. And I don't know what the hell was up with BRICS answer...

Comment: @MagicMan: I think that some people are using LaTex keyboards or something like that, otherwise, it is beyond my comprehension as to how fast some of the answers are being posted here. The only cases where I can match that speed are with those induction questions, where I mostly just need to copy-paste a previous answer of mine.

Comment: @barakmanos Unfortunately, there are some bad practices when posting answers. Many people post incomplete ones and edit, edit, edit during the grace period to have the earliest time stamp and the like (maybe even delete, then undelete). Maybe I should do that haha. I won't. I think I'm pretty good at $\rm\LaTeX$ and I type stuff up pretty quickly, but you're right in how fast some of it comes out seems unnatural. I think part of it really is due to poor etiquette no?

Comment: @MagicMan: I mostly agree, and would be happy to continue this conversation, but I'm off to the gym, so we'll continue that on the next induction question ... :)

Comment: @barakmanos Sounds like a good idea! Go pump some iron my friend. Cheerio!

Comment: @user3699546: I added a proof by modular-arithmetic, which you might find useful in similar cases (should you choose or instructed **not** to use induction).

Answer (score 2):

I think you would want to make things more compact instead of expanding. We have $$k^4+2k^3+k^2 = k^2(k^2+2k+1) = k^2(k+1)^2 = [k(k+1)]^2$$ Now if we suppose that $[k(k+1)]^2$ is divisible by $4$ for all $k \in \{1,2,\ldots n\}$ then we can consider $$[(n+1)(n+2)]^2$$ Since $n$ is an integer, then either $n+1$ is even or $n+2$ is even. WLOG, suppose $n+2 = 2p$ is even. Then $$[(n+1)(n+2)]^2 = [(n+1)(2p)]^2 = 4[(n+1)p]^2 = 4q$$ for some integer $q$. I don't know if this really counts as induction since you don't use the induction hypothesis to show $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$. This argument can be completed simply by the fact that for any positive integer $n$, $n+1$ $n$ must be even.

Comment: Thank you, I never would have thought to solve it like this before.

Comment: You are welcome. Do you have to prove this with induction, though? Analyzing the structure of $[n(n+1)]^2$ in the light of $n$ or $n+1$ being even just seems like an easier way to do this one.

Comment: I think that's what was expected of me, but I don't think it's as straightforward (at least to me) as proving it directly like you did.

Answer (score 2):

First note that $n^4+2n^3+k^2= n^2(n^2+2n+1)=n^2(n+1)^2$. Hence, the problem is to show that for every $n\geq 1$, 
$$
S_n : 4\mid n^2(n+1)^2
$$
is true.

---

Without induction, the direct proof follows from the fact that among $n$ and $n+1$, one is even, and so one of $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ has a factor of $4$. But we will do it by induction anyway.

---

**Base step:** When $n=1, n^2(n+1)^2=4$, so $S_1$ holds.

**Inductive step:** Let $k\geq 1$ and let the induction hypothesis be that $S_k$ holds; in particular, suppose that $m$ is such that $k^2(k+1)^2=4m$. It remains to show that
$$
S_{k+1} : 4\mid (k+1)^2(k+2)^2
$$
follows. Indeed
\begin{align}
(k+1)^2(k+2)^2 &= (k^2+4k+4)(k+1)^2\\[0.5em]
&= k^2(k+1)^2+(4k+4)(k+1)^2\\[0.5em]
&= 4m+4(k+1)(k+1)^2\quad\text{(by $S_k$)}
\end{align}
shows that $(k+1)^2(k+2)^2$ is also divisible by $4$, concluding the proof of $S_{k+1}$ and hence the inductive step.

By mathematical induction, it is true that for any positive integer $n$, the number $n^2(n+1)^2$ is divisible by $4$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: $$S_{k+1}\!-S_k = ((k\!+\!1)(k\!+\!2))^2\!-(k(k\!+\!1))^2 =\, ((k\!+\!2)^2\!-\!k^2)(k\!+\!1)^2 =\, \color{#c00}4(k\!+\!1)(k\!+\!1)^2$$

Comment: @BillDubuque This idea is shown in Mark Bennet's answer.

Comment: @user31415 Notice that they were posted within a minute of each other,

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this. As others have noted you have $$f(k)=k^4+2k^3+k^2=k^2(k+1)^2$$ and you are done if you can prove that $k(k+1)$ is even, because then its square is divisible by $4$ (an extra step you have to prove if you want to simplify the induction).

Now this is trivially true for $k=0$ and if true for $k=r$ we have $$(r+1)(r+2)=r(r+1)+2(r+1)$$$r(r+1)$ is even by inductive hypothesis, and $2(r+1)$ is even because it is divisible by $2$, so $(r+1)(r+2)$ is even.

---

If you want to keep the squares/fourth powers in, you can compute the difference between successive values as $$(n+1)^2(n+2)^2-n^2(n+1)^2=(n+1)^2\left((n+2)^2-n^2\right)$$

The second term is a difference of two squares equal to $2\cdot (2n+2)=4(n+1)$ so the difference is divisible by $4$. Again this avoids any full expansion of the expressions involved.